# Metepreter doesn't have root access on rooted phone

Tags: android, root, metasploit

I am currently testing how msfvenom for android works with it's source code. Well the AVD device that i'm testing is rooted but the backdoor doesn't have the root access. `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");` didn't worked. 
Does anyone knows why it doesn't work?

[Metepreter session's picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KNFTQ.png)

```
 try
        {
            Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
            process.waitFor();
        }
```

Comment: which API level does your AVD has @Elliot

Comment: It's API 23 @Tej

Comment: From API 23 , Android introduce Run time Permission Module . So you cant  get super user privilege. @Elliot